# Bilheteria de cinema Python exibir posição de assentos ocupados

Tags: python

Estou fazendo um programa usando matrizes que funciona como uma bilheteria de cinema.

Estou trabalhando pra terminar a opção 1 (que na minha opinião é a mais trabalhosa). Consegui trocar os valores na matriz para que ao invés do número apareça `xx` quando o usuário escolher o lugar onde quer se sentar.

Meu maior problema é na hora de dizer que o assento escolhido já está ocupado e mostrar a posição onde ele está ocupado. E se selecionar 2 locais para se sentar, caso um desses lugares esteja ocupado, ele não pode marcar o local valido com `xx` (os 2 lugares ficam inválidos para serem preenchidos no momento).

Parte onde printa o lugar escolhido com `xx`:

```
    for linha in range(entrada_linhas):
        for coluna in range(entrada_colunas):
            if str(m[linha][coluna]).zfill(2) in valores_assentos:
                #adicionando xx nas posições escolhidas
                m[linha][coluna] = "xx"
            print(str(m[linha][coluna]).zfill(2), end="\t")
        print()
    for assentos_ocupados in valores_assentos:
        print("Assento escolhido:", str(assentos_ocupados).replace("0", ""))`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def IngressosCinemas(posicao,assentos):
   for p,j in enumerate(assentos):
     for o,k in enumerate(j):
       if(posicao==k):
          matriz[p][o] = "XX"
```

A variável posicao é os assentos escolhidos, e a variavel assentos é uma lista com todos assentos do cinema.